# AJAX problems with sending POST, and getting result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web

Im new at JS and JSON. So I need to send a JSON massive to Google API using POST, and get the answer and show it via alert. I wrote this page, but this code has no result.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Redericting</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=KEY',
        data: '{wifiAccessPoints:["macAddress", "signalStrength"], cellTowers:["cellId", "locationAreaCode", "mobileCountryCode", "mobileNetworkCode"]}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);

        }
    });

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you are not passing json data but string value in data attribute

Comment: your data object should be  `data: {wifiAccessPoints:["macAddress", "signalStrength"], cellTowers:["cellId", "locationAreaCode", "mobileCountryCode", "mobileNetworkCode"]}`, // remove single-quotes around

Comment: @serdar.sanri Thank you, it was mistake. But there is no response now too

Comment: add an error handler and display the result, use developer tools to determine what the server response is to your ajax post.

Comment: I would look at documentation. When I add my key and test it I get a 400 error response. it might be different on your end. try to add `success:function(){//your code},error:function(details){console.log(details)}` to pinpoint what the actual error you are receiving.

Comment: @Steve Chrome showed me error 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @Aleksandr As it should, that is invalid json.

Comment: as per the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en_US you are not passing vaild data to the function

Answer (score 0):

When using AJAX you require to set the content-type of the information you are sending. By default this value is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=KEY',
    data: JSON.stringify({wifiAccessPoints:["macAddress", "signalStrength"], cellTowers:["cellId", "locationAreaCode", "mobileCountryCode", "mobileNetworkCode"]}),
    contentType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks to @kevin-b for catching the request body issue.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sending the response in JSON format? datatype property refers to the type that you're returning from the server. And if that doesn't match, control will go the error callback. Remove or update the datatype property to match the response type. Make the below changes and try

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=KEY',
        data: '{wifiAccessPoints:["macAddress", "signalStrength"], cellTowers:["cellId", "locationAreaCode", "mobileCountryCode", "mobileNetworkCode"]}',            
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR,  textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```